# How to replace text from #include .asp file to another .asp file

Tags: asp-classic

Working with a very simple `.asp` (*page1.asp*) page as shown below (legacy code):

```
<body>
    <!--#include file="../com/body_begin.asp"-->    
        <%
           Response.Write "<h3><b>Title / ABCD<b></h3></br>"    
        %>      
    <!--#include file="../com/body_end.asp"-->
</body>
```

**Questions:** There are some text in the *body_begin.asp* file which needs to be replaced (which is inside `Response.Write`). I can not change it witin the file because that is used in other `.asp` pages.

**Questions:** How can I alter/remove/replace that text into the current page(*page1.asp*)?

**Code:** *body_begin.asp*

```
    if (level="" or selection="") then 
    Response.Write "<h3><b>Please select a City from the menu<b></h3></br>" 
    else

    if accessOK=false then
    Response.Write "<h3>User <b>"&userName&"</b> do not have access to this page.</h3>"       
    end if
```

The `end if` of the first `if` statement usually is in every `.asp` page.

Comment: can you post your code for body_begin.asp ?

Comment: @Rafael :code is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a common include file for multiple pages, it's important to keep the contents of that include as general as possible to fit in all the places where it would be used. That being said, you can modify the "../com/body_begin.asp" page to look at ServerVariables... here are two possible examples:

```
<%
thisURL =  Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL") 
thatURL = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

If thisURL Then
   Response.Write "One Thing"
Else
   Response.Write "Another Thing"
End
%>
```

Note that this is sort of a Band-Aid and is not the best form if you might have many different variations. The more exceptions you allow in a generic markup the harder it is to maintain your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to go:

1) instead of using Response.Write use Function which are return result as string value

2) copy of body_begin.asp to body_begin2.asp and make changes you need in file body_begin2.asp

3) check request page name, see sample below:

Make following changes in file **body_begin.asp** to check what page was requested. Depending on page name you will output one or other result. I suppose that file "Page1.asp" located in web site root folder.

```
<%
    If LCase(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")) = "/page1.asp" Then
        Response.Write "Ho ho!"
    Else
        Response.Write "Ha ha!"
    End If
%>
```